# OAuth 2.0 - Account Managment for own website

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, authorization, owin, identity

I'm creating an OAuth 2.0 service and was following the guide here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server . I got half way through the guide and was experimenting with a few things.

An was wondering why `OnGrantResourceOwnerCredentials` is never called. It also mentions in the account management section in the tutorial that they won't be checking for account management.

However i thought that this would be handled in `OnGrantResourceOwnerCredentials` but it seems like it should be handled in the controller?

Any clear up on the above would be much appreciated.

TL;DR

Where should the login be checked? in the controller or in `OnGrantResourceOwnerCredentials`?

If the answer is `OnGrantResourceOwnerCredentials` how come it's never called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this isn't really an *answer*, per se, but I will tell you that you are probably going down the wrong path if you want to do OAuth with your web apis.  OAuth is not something that you want to implement yourself.  It is far too complicated to do yourself unless you do that kind of thing for a living.

If you want to learn more about using OAuth, I would recommend that you consider something like [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4), which acts as an IdP that supports a number of different protocols, including Auth2.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you and yes i did end up using Identity server and it sorted alot of the technical problems i was having out.

Answer (score 0):

GrantResourceOwnerCredentials This method is overwriten so it run automatically and it check the membership database for username and password . I Suggest You to follow this link its more precise and correct :-

Link:-

> http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Comment: I was actually using this very tutorial as a bases for some finer details and couldn't see how the token endpoint was actually called, it was probably in one of the JS scripts. But the method your talking about is only called if the token endpoint is called as in ... MyLogin/TokenEndpoint which you could have as a redirect on login but it becomes more and more ugly if you do it this way.